# Box2d - Is there a way to check whether there is a body at a specific location?

Tags: android, box2d

In my game, a body is randomly relocated on the screen after the user does something. However, if the object is relocated on top of another body, then both are pushed slightly (to make room!). I would like to check the location of the randomly generated coordinates first, so that the relocation only takes place if the position is free (within a certain diameter anyway).

Something like.. location.hasBody(). There surely must be a function  for this that I haven't found. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to query a world with a point and get the body, but what you can do is query the world with a small box:

```
// Make a small box.
b2AABB aabb;
b2Vec2 d;
d.Set(0.001f, 0.001f);
aabb.lowerBound = p - d;
aabb.upperBound = p + d;

// Query the world for overlapping shapes.
QueryCallback callback(p);
m_world->QueryAABB(&callback, aabb);

if (callback.m_fixture)
{
    //it had found a fixture at that position
}
```

Solution originally posted here: [Cocos2d-iphone forum](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/detecting-if-point-is-inside-of-a-box2d-dynamic-body/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if `box2d` includes a 'clean' way to do it. I'd just manually iterate over all bodies in the world just before adding a new one, and `manually` check if their positions + radio/size overlap with the new body shape.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
b2Vec2 vec = body->GetPosition(); // in meters
```

or

```
CGPoint pos = ccp(body->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO, body->GetPosition().y * PTM_RATIO); // in pixels
```